# Unable to get menu pattern using a walker

Tags: menus

I am trying, for about a week, to create menu in below pattern....

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li></li>

<li class="drop"><a href="#">About<i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-lg padding-left"></i></a>

<ul class="dropdown">
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li class="drop"><a href="#">My Experience<i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-lg padding-left"></i></a>

<ul class="dropdown">
   <li></li>
</ul>
```

Right now, my menu looks like this....

```
<ul id="menu-main" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li id="menu-item-78" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="#">Sample page</a></li>

<li id="menu-item-79" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children drop"><a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <ul>
     <li id="menu-item-80" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="#">Link 2</a>
     </li>
 </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

My walker is as below.....

```
class CSS_Menu_Walker extends Walker {

var $db_fields = array('parent' => 'menu_item_parent', 'id' => 'db_id');

function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul>\n";
}

function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
}

function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {

    global $wp_query;
    $indent = ($depth) ? str_repeat("\t", $depth) : '';
    $class_names = $value = '';
    $classes = empty($item->classes) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

    /* Add active class */
    if (in_array('current-menu-item', $classes)) {
        $classes[] = 'active';
        unset($classes['current-menu-item']);
    }

    /* Check for children */
    $children = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'nav_menu_item', 'nopaging' => true, 'numberposts' => 1, 'meta_key' => '_menu_item_menu_item_parent', 'meta_value' => $item->ID));
    if (!empty($children)) {
        $classes[] = 'drop';
    }

    $class_names = join(' ', apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class', array_filter($classes), $item, $args));
    $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr($class_names) . '"' : '';

    $id = apply_filters('nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args);
    $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr($id) . '"' : '';

    $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

    $attributes  = ! empty($item->attr_title) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr($item->attr_title) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty($item->target)     ? ' target="' . esc_attr($item->target    ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty($item->xfn)        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr($item->xfn       ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty($item->url)        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr($item->url       ) .'"' : '';

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters('the_title', $item->title, $item->ID) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    $output .= apply_filters('walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args);
}

function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    $output .= "</li>\n";
}
}
```

Menu print is as....

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array(
'menu' => 'Main Menu', 
'container' => 'ul',
'container_id' => '',
'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
'walker' => new CSS_Menu_Walker()
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

done. Used items_wrap

```
'items_wrap' => '<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">%3$s</ul>',
```

changed

```
$output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown\">\n";
```

Used if (!empty($children)) for $item_output for '' '>';

Comment: Now not from system. But you try, create a class variable and set it's value based on whether have children. Then append that <¡> tag based on it's value.

Comment: @KrishnadasPC no. could not make it work. i think i should go without <i> tag.